# Hilbert-Samuel multiplicity of standard graded $k$-algebra which is an integral domain and $k$ is algebraically closed

Tags: commutative-algebra, cohen-macaulay, projective-varieties, hilbert-polynomial, graded-algebras

Let $R=\oplus_{i\ge 0} R_i $ be a graded  domain such that $R_0=k$ is an algebraically closed field, $R$ is finitely generated $k$-algebra and $R=k[R_1]$. Let $d=\dim R>0$. Let $\mathfrak m=\oplus_{i>0}R_i$ be the unique homogeneous maximal ideal of $R$, so that $\dim_k R_i=\mu(\mathfrak m^i),\forall i\ge 1$. Let $e(R)=(d-1)!\lim_{n\to \infty}\dfrac {\mu(\mathfrak m^n)}{n^{d-1}}$ denote the Hilbert-Samuel multiplicity of $R$.

My question is: Is it true that $e(R)\ge \dim_k R_1 - \dim R +1 $ ?

I know this is true if $R$  is Cohen-Macaulay by Abhyankar's inequality, but even if $R$ is not Cohen-Macaulay, I think I have seen this inequality being used in articles/papers dealing with projective varieties, hence my question .

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes, this is true. See, for example, Theorem 4.3 [here](https://www.bprim.org/sites/default/files/JKV-BP22July2018-RingsMinMultiplicity.pdf). The proof is also in [Abhyankar's original paper](https://www.jstor.org/stable/2373418?seq=1), but this is harder to access.

Comment: I'm assuming you meant Theorem 4.3 ? But then again the write up only gives a proof in dimension 2 ... do you know of any other reference of the proof in any dimension apart from Abhyankar's paper ?

Comment: @user521337 As is mentioned at the end of Theorem 4.3, the general case follows from the dimension 2 case by way of Bertini's theorem. Everything I know of cites Abhyankar's paper since he's the one who proved it so I would just try and access that if you want to see the details.

Comment: Okay, thanks ... (I actually found another proof in Herrmann and Orbanz book Equimultiplicity and Blowup , where they discuss various related issues. )